# Hide woocommerce-checkout-review-order table for specific product categories in WooCommerce cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart, checkout

i would like to hide the woocommerce checkout-review-order table for specific product categories in WooCommerce cart category "X"

I'm using the code below for this, but it does not hide the table

```php
function conditional_checkout_fields_products( $fields ) {
  $cart = WC()->cart->get_cart();

  foreach ( $cart as $item_key => $values ) {
      $product = $values['data'];

      if ( $product->id == 168 ) {
          unset( $fields['order']['order_review'] );
      }
  }

  return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'conditional_checkout_fields_products' );
//OTHER HOOK add_filter(  'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

---

Any help with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the woocommerce checkout-review-order table, you can use:

```php
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

---

To hide the woocommerce checkout-review-order table for specific product categories in WooCommerce cart

You can use:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_order_review() {
    // Specific categories: the term name/term_id/slug. Several could be added, separated by a comma
    $categories = array( 63, 15, 'categorie-1', 'categorie-2' );
    
    // Initialize
    $flag = false;
    
    // WC Cart
    if ( WC()->cart ) {
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $categories, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {               
                $flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // True
    if ( $flag ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );       
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 5 );
```

Comment: Perfect.Can you pls explain a bit for my knowledge as why unset didn't work.Thanks

Comment: @thedreamfullile because it is not about a field which is part of the other checkout fields, but about a table